# Error installing Proftp Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian

I always install Proftp on Centos and it works well.
I am now installing on Debian 9 and there is an error in the configuration file.
Installation is no problem.

And the configuration file is what the installation creates, I do not change anything in the file and this error already exists.

```
root@altais:~# systemctl status proftpd
● proftpd.service - LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/proftpd; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-07-31 16:45:57 -03; 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 45717 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/proftpd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 31 16:45:57 altais systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon...
Jul 31 16:45:57 altais proftpd[45717]: Starting ftp server: proftpd2020-07-31 16:45:57,902 altais proftpd[45724]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'altais'
Jul 31 16:45:57 altais proftpd[45717]: 2020-07-31 16:45:57,902 altais proftpd[45724]: error: no valid servers configured
Jul 31 16:45:57 altais proftpd[45717]: 2020-07-31 16:45:57,902 altais proftpd[45724]: fatal: error processing configuration file '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'
Jul 31 16:45:57 altais proftpd[45717]:  failed!
Jul 31 16:45:57 altais systemd[1]: proftpd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 31 16:45:57 altais systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon.
Jul 31 16:45:57 altais systemd[1]: proftpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 31 16:45:57 altais systemd[1]: proftpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
root@altais:~#
```

Has anyone been there and can you help me?

Comment: I believe that this is not the problem. IP discovery, but something in the configuration file.

Comment: I finished solving the problem with the IP, and this is the same problem. I changed the /etc/hosts file and it worked.